# Mongoimport import json array as collection not as key in collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I am attempting to seed a database with a json array of data with mongoimport, however when the data reaches the mongo collection, it imports as a key in the collection object like this:

"items" is my json file, it always shows up as "items", I want the parent array to be the array I'm trying to import itself, does this make sense?

**Update**

Please see this example, the first image is how mongoimport is importing this array of objects:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc01ecec116d4c9039e47c"), "items" : [ { "id" : 1, "_id" : "item1", "type" : "alert", "title" : "hello.world", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$9.00", "active" : true }, { "id" : 2, "_id" : "item2", "type" : "welcome.lol", "title" : "Item 2", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "lol", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : true }, { "id" : 3, "_id" : "item3", "type" : "message", "title" : "various.domain", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "lol", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$3.00", "active" : false }, { "id" : 4, "_id" : "item4", "type" : "message", "title" : "something.else", "message" : "", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : false }, { "id" : 5, "_id" : "item5", "type" : "update", "title" : "wow.lol", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : false }, { "id" : 6, "_id" : "item6", "type" : "update", "title" : "domainname.net", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "cars", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : false }, { "id" : 7, "_id" : "item7", "type" : "update", "title" : "something.lol", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : false } ] }
```

Notice how its treats the entire array as an "item" object, with a key in the item "items" which is the array, I want the data to look like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc027a2c74df002a957281"), "price" : "asdf", "message" : "asdf", "email" : "aasfd", "title" : "asdf", "dateCreated" : ISODate("2017-03-29T18:52:42.227Z"), "active" : true, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc027b2c74df002a957282"), "price" : "asdf", "message" : "asdf", "email" : "aasfd", "title" : "asdf", "dateCreated" : ISODate("2017-03-29T18:52:43.574Z"), "active" : true, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc027b2c74df002a957283"), "price" : "asdf", "message" : "asdf", "email" : "aasfd", "title" : "asdf", "dateCreated" : ISODate("2017-03-29T18:52:43.708Z"), "active" : true, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc027b2c74df002a957284"), "price" : "asdf", "message" : "asdf", "email" : "aasfd", "title" : "asdf", "dateCreated" : ISODate("2017-03-29T18:52:43.855Z"), "active" : true, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc027b2c74df002a957285"), "price" : "asdf", "message" : "asdf", "email" : "aasfd", "title" : "asdf", "dateCreated" : ISODate("2017-03-29T18:52:43.994Z"), "active" : true, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc027c2c74df002a957286"), "price" : "asdf", "message" : "asdf", "email" : "aasfd", "title" : "asdf", "dateCreated" : ISODate("2017-03-29T18:52:44.128Z"), "active" : true, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc027c2c74df002a957287"), "price" : "asdf", "message" : "asdf", "email" : "aasfd", "title" : "asdf", "dateCreated" : ISODate("2017-03-29T18:52:44.263Z"), "active" : true, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc027c2c74df002a957288"), "price" : "asdf", "message" : "asdf", "email" : "aasfd", "title" : "asdf", "dateCreated" : ISODate("2017-03-29T18:52:44.391Z"), "active" : true, "__v" : 0 }
```

Where each item in the array is created as an "item" in mongo, each with its own ObjectID - otherwise it's useless for CRUD applications.

Docker MongoDB Log:

```
mongodb_1       | 2017-03-29T21:38:09.439+0000 I COMMAND  [conn1] command reach-engine.domains command: insert { insert: "domains", documents: [ { items: [ { id: 1, _id: "item1", type: "alert", title: "hello.world", email: "something@something.com", message: "", createdDate: "date", price: "$9.00", active: true }, { id: 2, _id: "item2", type: "welcome.lol", title: "Item 2", email: "something@something.com", message: "lol", createdDate: "date", price: "$12.00", active: true }, { id: 3, _id: "item3", type: "message", title: "various.domain", email: "something@something.com", message: "lol", createdDate: "date", price: "$3.00", active: false }, { id: 4, _id: "item4", type: "message", title: "something.else", message: "", createdDate: "date", price: "$12.00", active: false }, { id: 5, _id: "item5", type: "update", title: "wow.lol", email: "something@something.com", message: "", createdDate: "date", price: "$12.00", active: false }, { id: 6, _id: "item6", type: "update", title: "domainname.net", email: "something@something.com", message: "cars", createdDate: "date", price: "$12.00", active: false }, { id: 7, _id: "item7", type: "update", title: "something.lol", email: "something@something.com", message: "", createdDate: "date", price: "$12.00", active: false } ] } ], writeConcern: { getLastError: 1, w: 1 }, ordered: false } ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:40 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2, w: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 1, W: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { W: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 250ms
```

Comment: Hi iamwhitebox; rather than including a screenshot of the mongoimport command and output, could you paste the output into the question as text? [Text is encouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors), because it makes the question easier to index, transcribe, and understand.

Comment: ok thanks. updated.

Answer (score 34):

It would be useful to know what command you are using to import, but I just created a database an imported the following JSON with this command:

`mongoimport --db test --collection example --type json --file example.json --jsonArray`

Make sure you are using the `--jsonArray` flag

---

example.json

```
[
    {
        "color": "red",
        "value": "#f00"
    },
    {
        "color": "green",
        "value": "#0f0"
    },
    {
        "color": "blue",
        "value": "#00f"
    },
    {
        "color": "cyan",
        "value": "#0ff"
    },
    {
        "color": "magenta",
        "value": "#f0f"
    },
    {
        "color": "yellow",
        "value": "#ff0"
    },
    {
        "color": "black",
        "value": "#000"
    }
]
```

Comment: this will show up as an "item" in your mongo collection, complete with ObjectID, and that object will have a "items" : [ ] array in it which will be your collection

Comment: So you have an array of parent objects, and each parent has a set of items. You want your collection to contain all the items?

Comment: With the clarity of your question, the solution I provided still achieves that outcome. See the output: http://i.imgur.com/xS5Jmpm.png

Comment: ah yes I see this doing the same thing on my local, however my actual database is on a docker container - and is producing different results. so weird! upvoted.

Comment: I'm actually running mongo in docker as well, though locally. Might be a JSON formatting issue?

Comment: the mongoimport message for my docker container is "imported 1 document", but if I run regular its "imported 7 documents" - so its obviously wrapping the json in an object, why I have no idea yet.

Comment: I was getting "Failed: error unmarshaling bytes on document #0: JSON decoder out of sync - data changing underfoot?" because I was forgetting the --jsonArray in my command. Adding it solved the problem and objects in the array were imported as individual documents.